# Deduce type based on enum value in an operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, enums

I really want to make the following code compile:

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>

enum class type {
    integer, string
};

template<typename T>
struct foo {
    type type_;
    T val_;

    foo(type t) : type_{std::move(t)} {}
    static foo<T> set(T val) {
        foo<T> result;
        result.val_ = std::move(val);
        return result;
    }

    template<typename T2>
    friend foo<T2> operator|(const foo<T2>& lhs, const foo<T2>& rhs) {
        // do something
        return rhs;
    }
};

template<typename T>
void test(foo<T>) {}
int main() {
    using foo_int = foo<int>;
    using foo_string = foo<std::string>;

    // what I want (they currently all don't compile)
    test(type::integer | foo_int::set(10)); // ok
    test(type::integer | foo_int::set("hello")); // error
    test(type::string | foo_string::set("hello")); // ok
    test(type::string | foo_string::set(10)); // error
}
```

The above is also my current attempt. The only thing that I think it is missing is the deduction of `T` when passing a `type` to the constructor, and as a result it currently doesn't compile. I can't figure that part out. Every attempt to try to solve this results in me having to change the way to call `test`, which I don't want to ideally (but I didn't even make it to there.)

Does anyone have an idea how to make the last four lines either compile or not compile (see comments)?

<sub>I also didn't find a way to eliminate `foo_int` and `foo_string` , but I could live with it. Changing the semantics who not be ideal though, but I guess I could live with it if it is minimal (it's for a library, so it needs to stay relatively simple.)</sub>

Comment: What does this class do? Does it hold either a string or an integer?

Comment: @NirFriedman It holds properties, and the properties depend on another property of the class.

Comment: @Rakete1111 So `foo` holds neither a string nor an integer?  That seems surprising.  (You where asked "does it hold either a string or an integer", and you did not answer "yes")

Comment: @Yakk It can either hold a string or an integer, but that depends on the `type` type.

Comment: @Rakete1111 No, that depends on the `T` type.  The `type` type appears to do nothing.  You set it, then ignore it.  Do you *want* `foo` to hold one of an `int`  or a `string`?  Have you seen `boost::variant<int, std::string>`?

Comment: @Yakk Well yes, but it should not compile if the `type` doesn't match `T`. So it does depend on `type`.

Comment: @Rakete1111 A runtime value cannot make code not compile.  Runtime happens after compile time.  You also lack any code that uses `type` at all, so it is unclear what you mean "make the code compile" involving `type`.  Again, have you seen `boost::variant`?  A "no, I have not seen it" is a short and simple answer, as is "yes, I have seen that".  Further elaboration is good, but answers are better than no answers.

Comment: How about making enum value a template parameter?

Comment: I do know that, but I would have thought that it could be possible to see which `type` is used. But I actually have no idea, and that's why I'm asking. If this is not possible, then I'll have to think about something else.

Comment: @Yakk And yes, I didn't think of that. I'll see if I can use that.

Comment: First, you need a default ctor :-). Second, is "error" supposed to be a compiler error? Third, why not an extra `operator|` function like [this code I wrote](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BacXKavR65rLtnoJ)?

Comment: Uhm so long story short instead of making the code compile you should just take a step back and figure out what it is you are actually trying to do. This code already represents some mistakes in thinking so making "this code" work is not really going to fix your problem.

Comment: @AndyG Wow, I didn't think of that for some reason. Thanks :)

Comment: @NirFriedman Ok will do, thanks

Comment: To his favor, an enum constant is not a runtime value, though

Answer (score 2):

You need to rethink your design. I'm not super-confident with Template Metaprogramming (which is what you appear to be trying to do) but here's the approach I would take:

```
#include<string>

enum class type {
    integer, string
};

template<type T>
struct foo_impl {
    static constexpr bool is_valid = false;
    typedef void Type;
};

template<>
struct foo_impl<type::integer> {
    static constexpr bool is_valid = true;
    typedef int Type;
};

template<>
struct foo_impl<type::string> {
    static constexpr bool is_valid = true;
    typedef std::string Type;
};

template<type T>
struct foo {
    static_assert(foo_impl<T>::is_valid, "Not a valid type!");

    using Type = typename foo_impl<T>::Type;
    Type value;

    foo(Type v) : value(std::move(v)) {}

    friend foo operator|(type const& lhs, foo const& rhs) {
        // do something
        return rhs;
    }
};

template<type T>
void test(foo<T>) {}
int main() {
    using foo_int = foo<type::integer>;
    using foo_string = foo<type::string>;

    // what I want (they currently all don't compile)
    test(type::integer | foo_int(10)); // ok
    //test(type::integer | foo_int(std::string("hello"))); // error
    test(type::string | foo_string(std::string("hello"))); // ok
    //test(type::string | foo_string(10)); // error
}
```

Note that I've left a lot of this code unimplemented (I ditched `foo::set` entirely) because it's not clear to me what actual functionality is meant to be wrung from this code. But you'll see this code implemented in [Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/MQ0zDs) compiles, and [fails to compile](http://ideone.com/dpzOLk) the moment you try to uncomment one of the lines at the end.

Note I had to explicitly construct a `std::string` at the end; the compiler can't deduce that a `const char *` is meant to be a `std::string` outside the context of implicit casting.

Comment: Thanks! I actually have many different properties, so I have many different `set` functions. I'll see what I can do though. :)

Comment: Replace `{ static constexpr bool is_valid = false; typedef void Type;};` with `{}` in `foo_impl`; an empty body generates solid SFINAE.  Or leave the `is_valid` if you like for better error messages.  Also, `template<type T> using foo_impl_t = typename foo_impl<T>::Type;` lets you do `using Type=foo_impl_t<T>;` (get rid of `typename` spam there).